# getting different results from the same query according to the value of a variable

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, where-clause

suppose we have the following masterdata:

```
order_type: [classic, transport]
order_status: [new, active, delivered, finished]
```

and we have the order tables:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+
| order_id | order_type | order_status |
+==========+============+==============+
| 1        | classic    | new          |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 2        | classic    | active       |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 3        | transport  | active       |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 4        | transport  | delivered    |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 5        | classic    | finished     |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 6        | classic    | active       |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 7        | transport  | delivered    |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 8        | classic    | finished     |
+----------+------------+--------------+
```

what is requested is to have one single query that could return 2 different sets of data, according to the value of a given variable `v_order_status`:

- `v_order_status = 'del'` then only **transport orders** is retrieved:

  ```
  +----------+------------+--------------+
  | order_id | order_type | order_status |
  +==========+============+==============+
  | 3        | transport  | active       |
  +----------+------------+--------------+
  | 4        | transport  | delivered    |
  +----------+------------+--------------+
  | 7        | transport  | delivered    |
  +----------+------------+--------------+
  ```
- `v_order_status =`***`any other value or null`*** then we retrieve the **whole table**.

the desired SQL statement is to be used within a stored procedure, something like:

```
procedure process_orders (v_order_status in varchar2(3) default null)
as
begin
  for ord in (select order_id, order_type, order_status
                from orders
                where [here comes the tricky part])
  loop
    do_something (ord.order_id);
    ...
  end loop;
end process_orders ;
```

any ideas how to set the `where` clause in the SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean logic:

```
select order_id, order_type, order_status
from orders
where 
    (v_order_status = 'del' and order_type = 'transport')
    or v_order_status <> 'del' 
    or v_order_status is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE (v_order_status='del' AND order_type= 'transport') 
OR (v_order_status <> 'del' OR v_order_status is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the stored procedure language is PL/SQL.

- do not define v_order as default null, if necessary default 'active'
- simply use the variable in the where condition

  ```
    procedure process_orders(v_order_status in varchar2(3) )
    as
    begin
      for ord in (select order_id, order_type, order_status
                    from orders
                   where order_status = v_order_status
      loop
        do_something (ord.order_id);
        ...
      end loop;
    end process_orders ;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a procedure, you should use that to your advantage to make the select statement as simple as possible. Instead of creating a query with a complex where clause (which may cause performance issues), you should do whatever logic you need in your PL/SQL code, then execute a simple query.

In the example below, I created a local variable that has its value set based on the conditions you described, then uses that variable as the only condition in the where clause.  I added the `NVL (order_type, 'no_order_type')` logic just in case there were any orders without an order type, but if that is impossible than you can remove that `NVL` from the where clause.

#### Example

```
DECLARE
    PROCEDURE process_orders (p_order_status IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
    AS
        l_order_type   VARCHAR2 (20)
                           := CASE p_order_status WHEN 'del' THEN 'transport' ELSE NULL END;
    BEGIN
        FOR ord
            IN (SELECT order_id, order_type, order_status
                  FROM (SELECT 1 AS order_id, 'classic' AS order_type, 'new' AS order_status
                          FROM DUAL
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 2, 'classic', 'active' FROM DUAL
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 3, 'transport', 'active' FROM DUAL
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 4, 'transport', 'delivered' FROM DUAL
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 5, 'classic', 'finished' FROM DUAL
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 6, 'classic', 'active' FROM DUAL
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 7, 'transport', 'delivered' FROM DUAL
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 8, 'classic', 'finished' FROM DUAL) orders
                 WHERE NVL (order_type, 'no_order_type') =
                       NVL (l_order_type, NVL (order_type, 'no_order_type')))
        LOOP
            --do_something (ord.order_id);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Order ID: ' || ord.order_id);
        END LOOP;
    END process_orders;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Status: something');
    process_orders ('something');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Status: del');
    process_orders ('del');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Status: null');
    process_orders (NULL);
END;
```

#### Output

```
Status: something
Order ID: 1
Order ID: 2
Order ID: 3
Order ID: 4
Order ID: 5
Order ID: 6
Order ID: 7
Order ID: 8
Status: del
Order ID: 3
Order ID: 4
Order ID: 7
Status: null
Order ID: 1
Order ID: 2
Order ID: 3
Order ID: 4
Order ID: 5
Order ID: 6
Order ID: 7
Order ID: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to all the solutions provided, another option is to use dynamic sql and change the `for loop` construction for a `bulk collect` . This is what is called Dynamic SQL for Multirow Queries.

Something like that should work in your case.

**TEST CASE ELEMENTS**

```
SQL> create table orders ( order_id number, order_type varchar2(20) , order_status varchar2(20) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into orders
  2  with t ( order_id , order_type, order_status )
  3  as
  4  (
  5  select 1, 'classic'   , 'del' from dual union all
  6  select 2, 'classic'   , 'del' from dual union all
  7  select 3, 'transport' , 'act' from dual union all
  8  select 4, 'transport' , 'act' from dual union all
  9  select 5, 'transport' , 'fin' from dual union all
 10  select 6, 'classic'   , 'fin' from dual union all
 11  select 7, 'classic'   , 'fin' from dual union all
 12  select 8, 'transport' , 'act' from dual union all
 13  select 9, 'transport' , 'act' from dual
 14  )
 15  select * from t ;

9 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure process_orders ( v_order_status in varchar2 default null )
  2  is
  3     TYPE order_rt IS RECORD (
  4     order_id     number,
  5     order_type   varchar2(20),
  6     order_status varchar2(20)
  7     );
  8
  9     TYPE order_rt_aat IS TABLE OF order_rt INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
 10
 11     l_orders   order_rt_aat;
 12     v_sql      clob;
 13  BEGIN
 14
 15     v_sql := q'[ select order_id, order_type, order_status from orders ]' ;
 16     if v_order_status is not null
 17     then
 18                  v_sql := v_sql || ' where order_status = '''||v_order_status||''' ';
 19     end if;
 20
 21     execute immediate v_sql bulk collect into l_orders;
 22
 23     FOR indx IN 1 .. l_orders.COUNT
 24     LOOP
 25        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_orders (indx).order_id);
 26     END LOOP;
 27  END;
 28  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

**VERIFICATION**

**Run without input parameter**

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec process_orders ;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Run with a specific input parameter**

```
SQL> exec process_orders ( 'del' ) ;
1
2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

With agreement to other answers which uses `where` clause which are completely fine,

*As this particular requirement says `v_order_status = 'del'` then only transport orders is retrieved and `v_order_status =any other value or null` then we retrieve the whole table, for this purpose we can also use [decode](http://dba-oracle.com/t_decode_sql.htm) as one line statement*,

> **The Oracle docs note the following about the decode SQL function:*
> "DECODE compares a column or expression to search values, returning a result when there is a match. DECODE is similar to IF_THEN-ELSE logic."*

```
select *
  from
(
    select 1 order_id,'classic' order_type,'new' order_status from dual
    union all
    select 2,'classic','active' from dual
    union all
    select 3,'transport','active' from dual
    union all
    select 4,'transport','delivered' from dual  
)
where order_type = decode(&v_order_status,'del','transport',order_type);
```